# Strange compiler messages when using lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

So I've added the use of lambdas in a C++ project and now the compiler is giving output like this:

```
9>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxcallobj(13): warning C4800: 'BOOL' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
3>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxfunction(386) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Impl_no_alloc0<_Callable,_Rx>' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Callable=_MyWrapper,
3>              _Rx=bool
3>          ]
3>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxfunction(369) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::tr1::_Function_impl0<_Ret>::_Reset0o<_Myimpl,_Fty,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ret=bool,
3>              _Fty=`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>,
3>              _Ty=std::tr1::_Function_impl0<bool>,
3>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::tr1::_Function_impl0<bool>>
3>          ]
3>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\functional(113) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::tr1::_Function_impl0<_Ret>::_Reset<_Fx>(_Fty)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ret=bool,
3>              _Fx=`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>,
3>              _Fty=`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>
3>          ]
3>          ..\..\Common\IOFile.cpp(1162) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::function<_Fty>::function<`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>>(_Fx)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Fty=bool (void),
3>              _Fx=`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>
3>          ]
```

And the code for my lambda is:

In the .h:

```
typedef std::function<bool ()> RepeatingFunction;
static bool RepeatFileOperation(RepeatingFunction callback);

static bool Copy(CString file, CString copyFileName, bool failIfExists = true);
```

In the .cpp:

```
bool IOFile::RepeatFileOperation(RepeatingFunction callback)
{
    const int times_to_retry = 10;
    bool succeed = false;

    // Retry a few times if it doesn't work
    int retries = 0;
    do
    {
        // Perform the caller's action on the file
        succeed = callback();
    }
    while (!succeed && retries++ < times_to_retry);

    return succeed;
}

bool IOFile::Copy(CString file, CString copyFileName, bool failIfExists)
{
    return RepeatFileOperation([&] {
        return CopyFile(file, copyFileName, static_cast<BOOL>(failIfExists));
    });
}
```

The program still compiles just fine. I Googled the error and can find people getting similar messages but in their case the program doesn't build. In all cases it appears that their build errors are about forward declaration, but as I said mine builds fine and I'm including `<functional>` in the header file so it should be able to find it fine.

Are these messages something I should be worried about or are they just expected behaviour?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support lambdas, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Luke: please post the code snippet that triggers this messasge

Comment: @NeilKirk Hard as it is to believe, [they squeezed it in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608(v=vs.100).aspx), (well, most of it anyway). I guess the engineers that didn't feel like working on now-15-year-old C99 standard compliance had to have *something* to occupy their day.

Comment: Can you show both the *calling* code *and* the output *above* this (the actual warning/error that is generated. It doesn't just start with this).

Comment: I have added the code of the lambda and also added the line above the output. VS2010 can do lambdas, but it doesn't have full C++11 support.

Comment: Shouldn't your `[&]` be `[&]()`?

Comment: No, according to the spec it works without the `()` if there are no arguments. The problem isn't a compile error anyway, just odd output.

Comment: the warning `forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)` does not have anything to do with lambdas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CopyFile` doesn't return a `bool`, but you are implicitly casting its result to a `bool`. Just add an explicit cast `return static_cast<bool>(CopyFile(...`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. The large output given by the compiler threw me off where the problem was coming from.